# Update Numbers per click

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having trouble with making a Number go up every time i click an object

Html:

```
<li>click here <span id="1">0</span></li>
<li>click here <span id="2">0</span></li>
```

Jquery:

```
$( function() { 
    var a1 = 0; 
    var a2 = 0; 
    $("li").on("click", function() { 
        var $span = $(this).find("span"); 
        var $id = $span.id; 
        if($id == "1") {
           a1++; 
           $span.text(a1); 
        } 
        else if($id == "2") {
           a2++; 
           $span.text(a2); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Attention, ID begins with digits is illegal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
var $id = $span.attr('id');
```

instead of

```
var $id = $span.id;
```

working demo http://jsfiddle.net/qw10hwc6/

Answer (score 0):

I thin your way of accessing the id of the span is not correct, try $id=$span.attr("id"); instead and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the events Get the Id and put the content back via that ID

```
  $(function() { 
        var a1 = 0; 
        var a2 = 0; 
        $("li").on("click", function() {        
            var $id = $(this).find('span').attr('id'); 
            if($id == "1") {
               a1++; 
               $("#"+$id).text(a1); 
            } 
            else if($id == "2") {
               a2++; 
                $("#"+$id).text(a2); 
            } 
        }); 
    });
```

demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsp6jeLh/11/).